# Receiving mail from php on non-gmail account

Tags: php

I want to receive a mail from php web form on my datta.dhonde@coreathena.com
I am receiving the same on datta.dhonde@gmail.com but not able to receive it on non-gmail account like datta.dhonde@coreathena.com
The following is my code

```
<?php
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['msg'] ;
  $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;

  //datta.dhonde@gmail.com is working but not on datta.dhonde@coreathena.com
  mail( "datta.dhonde@coreathena.com", "Contact Us Form",
    $message, "From: $email $name $phone");
  header( "Location: http://core.coreathena.com/" );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
"From: $email $name $phone"
```

into

```
"From: $email"
```

But you never know what in $email variable is. When anyone put them aaa it's more likely won't be delivered (I don't see any email validation).

In fact more reliable method is to use dedicated class as for example phpmailer (look at http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ ) and send message via SMTP. Mail function is the easiest solution but from my experience you cannot trust that mails send via simple mail function will always be delivered.